# Exposing comparison/equality on a private union type

Tags: f#

I am struggling to expose comparison/equality on a union type whose cases are hidden. This is what I started with:

Module.FSI

```
type A<'T when 'T : comparison>
```

Module.FS

```
type A<'T when 'T : comparison> = A of 'T list
```

Program.FS

```
[<StructuralEquality;StructuralComparison>]
type B =
    | Case1
    | Case2 of Module.A<char>
```

But I get the error:

```
The struct, record or union type 'B' has the 'StructuralComparison'
attribute but the component type 'Module.A<char>' does not satisfy the
'comparison' constraint
```

I've tried using custom equality on A:

Module.FSI

```
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type A<'T when 'T : comparison>
  with
    interface System.IComparable
    override Equals : y:obj -> bool
    override GetHashCode : unit -> int
  end
```

Module.FS

```
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type A<'T when 'T : comparison> = A of 'T list
    with
        override x.Equals y = ...
        override x.GetHashCode() = ...
        interface System.IComparable with
            member x.CompareTo(y) = ...
```

But I get this:

```
This construct is deprecated: The syntax 'type X with ...' is reserved 
for augmentations. Types whose representations are hidden but which have
 members are now declared in signatures using 'type X = ...'.
```

Is this the right way to go about exposing comparison from an union type with private cases? What is the correct syntax for this in signature files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message only says that the correct syntax for the FSI file declarations should use `=` (as in the implementation file) instead of the `with ... end` syntax. However, that doesn't really solve the problem. After some experimantations, I think you don't need to apply the attributes in the FSI file:

```
// Mod.fs
namespace Mod

[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>] //; CustomEquality>]
type A<'T when 'T : comparison> = 
  | A of 'T list    
  override x.Equals y = compare x (y :?> A<_>) = 0
  override x.GetHashCode() = -1
  interface System.IComparable with
    member x.CompareTo(y) = compare x (y :?> A<_>)

// Mod.fsi
namespace Mod

[<Sealed>]
type A<'T when 'T : comparison> =
  interface System.IComparable
  override Equals : obj -> bool
  override GetHashCode : unit -> int
```

This should do the trick - unfortunatelly, I'm not sure if there is a way to use automatically generated structural equality and hide the implementation of the discriminated union at the same time.

**EDIT** It looks like you can specify the discriminated union cases in the FSI file, but mark them as `private`, so they won't be visible outside of the module. So maybe this would work too:

```
// Mod.fsi
namespace Mod

type A<'T when 'T : comparison> = 
  private | A of 'T list    

// Mod.fs
namespace Mod

[<StructuralComparisonAttribute; StructuralEqualityAttribute>] 
type A<'T when 'T : comparison> = 
  | A of 'T list
```

Comment: Brilliant! Adding [<Sealed>] and removing the other attributes fixed the problem. I had tried playing with them but clearly never hit up on the right combination. The need to add Sealed looks like a bug to me (or at least an unfortunate inconsistency). Unions are automatically sealed (or so the compiler says if I also add Sealed in the FS file).

Comment: @petebu - The `Sealed` attribute is intentional (the compiler just wants to you to explicitly state that fact in the F# interface file - although it wouldn't be needed when the interface file contains declaration of the type).